# Linux shell script arguments expansion when passed to another script

Tags: shell

I have 2 shell scripts let say a.sh and b.sh.
a.sh as follows.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    arg1="$1"   //contains path of b.sh
    arg2="$2"  //contains "-ab  'val1 val2'"
    arg3="$3"  //contains "val3"

    arg2=$(echo $arg2 | tr "'" '"')  // replace single quote with double quote 

    # call second shell script
   "b.sh" $arg2 $arg3
```

In b.sh.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    arg_b1="$1" //coming as "-ab"    - ok
    arg_b2="$2" //coming as "val1    - not ok  expecting "val1 val2"
    arg_b3="$3" //coming as val2"    - not ok expecting "val3"
```

I expect to get arg_b2 as "val1 val2" as they are within double quote while passing. But it is not the case.
Please help how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

a.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
arg1="$1"   # contains path of b.sh
arg2="$2"   # contains "-ab  'val1 val2'"
arg3="$3"   # contains "val3"

arg2=$( echo "$arg2" | tr "'" '"' )  # replace single quote with double quote

    # call second shell script
sh -c "\"$arg1\" $arg2 $arg3"
```

b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "{$1}"
echo "{$2}"
echo "{$3}"
```

I think this gives a result which corresponds to your intentions.